# how to make a word as hyperlink in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios

In my app, I have 4 values 0, 10, 20 and 30. each value contains diff url's. 
    I used UITextView to trigger the url when user taps it, but for value 20 I need a word should be present there instead of direct url.
    Now the user will tap on that word it should connect to that url for value 20. In-short I want a word to be tapped that will connect to some url.
    Any ideas???

Here is my code:

```
NSString *dot=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",addressInfo.category]; 
NSString *dotstr=@"20";
if ([dot isEqualToString:dotstr] ) {
 urlblue.text = @"eBrochure";
  self.urlblue.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;

}
```

whenever user taps "eBrochure", my app should opens the associated url.....?

Comment: you can use UIWebView for this purpose..

Comment: But Leena i need to use it in Textfield only

Answer (score 1):

Yes,U can use  UIWebView to do that.But if u just want to use Textfield,I think the link can help u.

[Tappable URLs in Core Text](http://www.netwalk.be/article/tappable-urls-core-text)

^-^

Answer (score 0):

You can draw it using this code:

```
CGRect underlineFrame = CGRectMake(textLabel.frame.origin.x, textLabel.frame.origin.y+textLabel.frame.size.height, textLabel.frame.size.width, 1);
UIView *viewUnderline=[[UIView alloc] init];
viewUnderline.frame=underlineFrame;
viewUnderline.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
[self addSubview:viewUnderline];
```